# Dynamical loading and displaying images collection in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

I'm using Telerik WPF controls but I'll appreciate any suggestions that might be helpful.
I have a **GridView** (**RadGridView** with **RadGridView.RowDetailsTemplate** actually, but it doesn't really matters). Also I have a collection of Images (It's actually a **ICollection** where items of this collection are relative Uris to the Images). Everything works fine if I have a fixed amount of Images in my collection, because I can create a fixed amount of **Image** controls in my View (XAML) and create a binding for each of these images in collection to each of my **Image** controls.

I want to create a mini-gallery. The question is how can I generate a non-fixed amount of **Image** controls to be shown in my **GridView.RowDetails** (or tell me if there is another way to display a list of images) during runtime. I'd like to know if there are few ways to do this (i.e. through binding in XAML and throught the Code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See here: [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use `CellTemplate` to do this.

Basically, you will need a collection of `ImageSource`/`Uri`, which will be the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`/`RadGridView`. This collection should implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and  `INotifyPropertyChanged`, e.g. `ObservableCollection<T>`. So you code behind or view model, you could build this collection dynamically, and bind the `Source` property of your `Image` in Xaml.

## Sample Code

Note the sample code here are for **MS** `DataGrid`, but the Telerik `RadGridView` has the similar interface, so you will be able to easily modify you code.

In Xaml, you could have something like following:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C# code will be like:

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<Uri>();
this.DataContext = items;
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    items.Add(new Uri("youimage.jpg"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your solution! In addition, if anybody else finds my question on StackOverflow he might be also interested in reading following [**topic**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0449bf6a-83a1-4783-8bb8-a6935b0a8a62/wpf-application-for-image-gallery?forum=wpf). Have a nice day.